# Weird Whitespace Above <img>

Tags: html, css, position

I've been working on a slider in JavaScript, and I've been adding images as backgrounds like so:

```
<img class="slide-bg" src="path/to/some/photo.jpg" />
```

CSS:

```
.slide-bg {
    position: absolute;
    filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px) grayscale(20%);
    z-index: -3;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This code, for some reason, yields this result:
[image]

Everything is great when I don't have `position: absolute`, but I need to have that so I can apply `z-index`and have the slide-content actually fit on top of the image. Without `position: absolute` it yields this result: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `top:0;` to your css

```
.slide-bg {
    position: absolute;
    filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px) grayscale(20%);
    z-index: -3;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top:0;
}
```